# After recovery from a primary failure, does Mongo Java driver resume normal write operations?

Tags: java, mongodb

So far from Mongo manuals, I learned that:

> (Mongo Server) ... the replica set will attempt to select another member to become the new primary. The first secondary that receives a majority of the votes becomes primary.
>
> (Client operation) ... Use primaryPreferred if you want an application to read from the primary under normal circumstances, but to allow stale reads from secondaries in an emergency.
>
> (Driver) The MongoDB Java driver handles failover in replicated setups with tuneable levels of transparency to the user. By default, a MongoClient connection object will ignore failures of secondaries, and reads will only throw a MongoException when the primary node is unavailable.

- When a new primary is elected by Mongo server, does the client driver become aware of the new primary?
- After a primary failure and new primary become elected, does the client driver resume normal write operations?

Comment: @Sammaye not sure, have you?

Comment: Yeah, took about 5 seconds to test, basically yes the driver to should provide automatic failover to new primary connection but really this is something that could have been tested easily

Comment: @Sammaye the driver manual does not advertise such feature, or maybe I have not looked hard enough.

Comment: It shouldn't, MongoDB proivdes automated failover, its drivers should be expected to recover, I would say that is why it isn't mentioned

Comment: I don't know the Java driver, but just as a cautious note: in the C# driver, it depends very much on what exactly is happening, and you do need code to handle failover. For instance, once you have acquired a `MongoCursor` for reading, it's tied to a socket and if the socket dies, the enumeration will fail. While I don't know for sure, I doubt that the Java driver handles socket exceptions internally, so you might want to check what exactly will be handled automatically and what not.

Comment: @mnemosyn of course its failure is based upon read preference, reading from primary should always result in a exception in failover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give MongoClient the list of replSet members, the driver will attempt to find the new primary once the election process is completed.

Comment: I have read mixed opinions on this topic, from which source did you get the impression?

Comment: Thank you. What happens if the new elected primary was not in replication set (because it was `rs.add()`ed later on) when the connection established, can the driver still discover the new primary?

Comment: You'll have to update your connection code to include the set member.